# Swashbuckle generate a polymorphic field

Tags: c#, polymorphism, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

i have a base class which has 2 derived classes and would like to map one field of the output to a "oneof" statement.

```
public class ClothingCollection
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
    public abstract class ClothingCollection<T> : ClothingCollection
    {
        public abstract string Type { get; }
        public abstract List<T> Stuff { get; }
    }
    public class PantsCollection : ClothingCollection<PantsModel>
    {
        public override string Type { get; } = "PANTS";
        public override List<PantsModel> Stuff { get; }
    }
    public class ShirtCollection : BaseItem<ShirtModel>
    {
        public override string Type { get; } = "SHIRT";
        public List<BarChartData> Data { get; }
    }
    public class PantsModel
    {
        public bool IsJeans { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShirtModel
    {
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
```

and set the controller response as such ...

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<ClothingCollection>), 200)]
[HttpGet("HelloWorld")]
public IActionResult HelloWorld()
{
....
}
```

and now would like the resulting swagger documentation to be List that looks somewhat like the following (if it's even possible)

```
{
    "Name": "string",
    "Id": "string",
    "type": "string",
    "Stuff":[
              anyof -> PantsCollection,
                       ShirtCollection
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The concept where you have exactly one value of one of several fixed types is called a [tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), discriminated union, or sometimes a either monad.

You could create a class that has either shirts or pants:

```
    public class ShirtOrPants
    {
        public ShirtCollection Shirts { get; }
        public PantsCollection Pants { get; }

        public ShirtOrPants(ShirtCollection shirts, PantsCollection pants)
        {
            Shirts = shirts;
            Pants = pants;
            if ((shirts == null) == (pants == null))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Must have shirts OR pants!");
            }
        }
    }
```

There are as far as I know no built in support for tagged unions in c# or any of the more popular serialization languages, so you would need some custom solution. You would typically add various methods to process either shirts or pants depending on which one has a value.

There are [generic implementations available](https://github.com/louthy/csharp-monad), but they might not be very helpful if the goal is to provide readable API definitions.